# Difficulties with scope and header files

Tags: c++

Probably a really simple fix, but I may as well ask anyways. I declared a variable in a header file and tried to use it in a source file, but I got an error saying it wasn't declared in the scope.

My header file:

```
#ifndef TILEMAP_H
#define TILEMAP_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "mapbuilder.h"

class tileMap : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
    public:
        tileMap();
        virtual ~tileMap();
        bool load(const std::string, sf::Vector2u, const int*, unsigned int, unsigned int);
    protected:

    private:
        sf::VertexArray m_vertices;
        sf::Texture m_tileset;
};

#endif // TILEMAP_H
```

My source file:

```
#include "tilemap.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "mapbuilder.h"

tileMap::tileMap()
{
    //ctor
}

tileMap::~tileMap()
{
    //dtor
}

bool load(const std::string& tileset, sf::Vector2u tileSize, const int* tiles, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    // load the tileset texture
    if (!m_tileset.loadFromFile(tileset))
        return false;

    // resize the vertex array to fit the level size
    m_vertices.setPrimitiveType(sf::Quads);
    m_vertices.resize(width * height * 4);

    // populate the vertex array, with one quad per tile
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
        {
            // get the current tile number
            int tileNumber = tiles[i + j * width];

            // find its position in the tileset texture
            int tu = tileNumber % (m_tileset.getSize().x / tileSize.x);
            int tv = tileNumber / (m_tileset.getSize().x / tileSize.x);

            // get a pointer to the current tile's quad
            sf::Vertex* quad = &m_vertices[(i + j * width) * 4];

            // define its 4 corners
            quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
            quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
            quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tileSize.x, (j + 1) * tileSize.y);
            quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, (j + 1) * tileSize.y);

            // define its 4 texture coordinates
            quad[0].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
            quad[1].texCoords = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
            quad[2].texCoords = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
            quad[3].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
        }

    return true;
}
```

Specifically, m_tileset and m_vertices don't seem to be declared in the load function, even though I defined them in the header file.

By the way, I'm new to C++, so please be gentle.

Comment: Did you mean `bool load` freestanding function, or `bool tileMap::load` member method?

Comment: `bool tileMap::load`, I think

Comment: show the stack trace and error

Answer (score 1):

Your load function is outside the proper namespace. Add "tileMap::" before load().

```
bool tileMap::load([params])
```